# How can I change the CSS visibility style for elements that are not on the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a lot of data being placed into a `<DIV>` with the `overflow: auto` style.  Firefox handles this gracefully but IE becomes very sluggish both when scrolling the div and when executing any Javascript on the page.

At first I thought IE just couldn't handle that much data in its DOM, but then I did a simple test where I applied the `visibility: hidden` style to every element past the first 100.  They still take up space and cause the scrollbars to appear.  IE no longer had a problem with the data when I did this.

So, I'd like to have a "smart" div that hides all the nested div elements which are not currently visible on the screen.  Is there a simple solution to this or will I need to have an infinite loop which calculates the location of the scrollbar?  If not, is there a particular event that I can hook into where I could do this?  Is there a jQuery selector or plugin that will allow me to select all elements not currently visible on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `display: none`  instead of `visibility: hidden`

Elements that are hidden using visibility: hidden will still claim their space in the viewport.

As far as using a "smart" div, as you describe it.  You may be interested in something like the [jQuery autopager plugin](http://lagoscript.org/jquery/autopager/demo).

Comment: The autopager plugin looks interesting... unfortunately I'm out of time to try different ideas to appease IE so I just removed most of the functionality on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the goal in my question but it did not deliver much of a performance gain in IE.  I reworked my whole page but here's the unfinished code in case anybody else wants to do something like this and wants to know where to start:

//Where 'child' = element inside of a `div` ('parent') having `overflow: auto` style

```
function isChildOnScreen(child, parent) { 
  var topOfChild = child.offsetTop;
  var bottomOfChild = child.offsetTop + child.offsetHeight;
  var topOfParent = parent.scrollTop;
  var bottomOfParent = parent.scrollTop + parent.offsetHeight;

  var makeVisible = (topOfChild >= topOfParent && topOfChild <= bottomOfParent)
    ||
    (bottomOfChild >= topOfParent && bottomOfChild <= bottomOfParent)
    ||
    (topOfChild < topOfParent && bottomOfChild > bottomOfParent);

  return makeVisible;
}
```